# SharePoint Online Admin Center Url

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, central-administration

I'm looking to validate a sharepoint online admin url, will this always be 
username-admin.sharepoint.com.

Would it be safe to say that if a url ends with -admin.sharepoint.com is valid admin site?

If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A valid admin site in Office 365 is always https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com

Tenant is the .onmicrosoft.com name that you choose when registering for a subscription. 
[Tenant Account Setup](http://office365support.ca/getting-started-with-office-365-the-basics/)

Whether you choose a vanity domain, change the name of your public website, the admin url always remains:
https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com

Answer (score 2):

By clicking this link https://admin.microsoft.com/sharepoint?page=home&modern=true, you will be able to find the SharePoint Online Admin Center URL.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to validate the SharePoint Tenant Admin URL is using ConditionalScope Class

Example Code

```
using (ClientContext SPOClientContext = new ClientContext(SPOUrl))
{
 SPOClientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(SPOCredential.UserName, SPOCredential.Password);
 Tenant oTenant = new Tenant(SPOClientContext);
 ConditionalScope Scope = new ConditionalScope(SPOClientContext, () => oTenant.ServerObjectIsNull.Value != true);
 SPOClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Reference: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535891(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If any one else comes across this the sharepoint admin can also be the following 
https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.de

Comment: sharepoint.de is German cloud only